# I'm working with laravel 5.6 Logs and i'm trying to store the user login data

Tags: laravel, logging

“I'm working with laravel 5.6 Logs and i'm trying to store the user login data such as "date,ip address...ect" .but in my log called "laravel.log" it shows only the error logs only”

Comment: i'm trying store the log data into laravel.log file

Answer (score 1):

Laravel utilizes [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) under the hood.

To log something explicitly, you can use the Log facade.

```
\Log::info("Some message");
```

This is, assuming, that your Log channel is configured to use either the `daily` or `single` log channels that write to the log file.

For more information, check the [documentation on Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging).